# Programmatically disable device in device manager (Vista x64)

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, device

Is there any way to programmatically disable a device? (preferably in .net, win32, or batch).

Most hits on google suggest using devcon but it does not seem to be working on Windows Vista/7 64bit.

[How do I disable a system device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252185/-net-how-do-i-disable-a-system-device) has a solution using SetupDiSetClassInstallParams but it also doesn't work for Vista64.

Comment: Any updates?  Ive got the same issue with my Window 7 laptop, cannot restart any of the USB devices via devcon.

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit version of `devcon` doesn't completely work in WoW64 emulation; I've seen it fail to disable devices as well. The [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/default.mspx) includes a 64-bit version of `devcon`, which works. It also includes the source code to `devcon`, so you can see that `devcon` is just a wrapper for the Setup API.

When you tried calling into the Setup API directly, was it from a 32-bit or 64-bit process? Based on experiences using `devcon`, I suspect that you need to call into the Setup API from a 64-bit process.