# Programmatically enabling/disabling hardware device

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages, hardware, device-driver

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [[.NET] How do I disable a system device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252185/net-how-do-i-disable-a-system-device)
>   [Win32 API function to programatically enable/disable device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device)

Is there a way, in C#, to programmatically disable and re-enable a device? I'm looking for essentially the same functionality that occurs when you go into device manager and right click on a device and disable or enable it. How can I do this in C#?

Comment: It's a double of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252185/net-how-do-i-disable-a-system-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [net-how-do-i-disable-a-system-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252185/net-how-do-i-disable-a-system-device).

Comment: You meant to comment this as a double, right? ;)

Comment: That looks a lot like it's just using handles to windows to do this and it doesn't appear to work anywhere like Vista, 7 or 2008 R2.  Interesting though.

Comment: @Abel - yeah, well at least I have done so now!

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/513855-can-i-use-wmi-c-disable-enable-device

> You need to interface with CfgMgr32
>   (Win32 API) to do this.

My first thought was to look at WMI but it's not there.

DevCon, which comes with the Device Drive Toolkit, provides a CLI to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541193(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I had no luck with the devcon tool.

Comment: Thank you, devcon works! What's your issue William Morrison?