# Disable 2nd USB keyboard

Tags: c#, windows-7, keyboard, windows-xp, usb

I have an environment where two (2) keyboards and two (2) mice are connected to a PC that may be running XP or Win7.  The purpose is to allow co-user interactions for training on a desktop.  At times I need a way to disable the 2nd kb/mouse for all user interactions.  I'm guessing this could be done either at the device HID level or at the USB level but need some C#/VB code that I could integrate into a system tray application.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything in window hooks that would tell you the source of the input and block it at that level.

You could go down the route of actually disabling the hardware completely through windows: [Programmatically enabling/disabling hardware device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498042/programmatically-enabling-disabling-hardware-device)