# How to disable windows tablet inbuilt webcam

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, camera, webcam

I want to make an application for my classroom where I want to disable tablet webcam. I want to restrict student's to use webcam while class is going on. However they can use it after. I just want to know how can I disable web cam using `c#` program.

Comment: Don't you want to do a little research first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498042/programmatically-enabling-disabling-hardware-device

Besides, we don't know what version of Windows your tablet is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [at least] two ways to do it:

1. Disable the device (see [Programmatically enabling/disabling hardware device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498042/programmatically-enabling-disabling-hardware-device)) similarly to interactive disable/enable action in Device Manager MMC snap-in.
2. Since webcam is exclusive use resource, your application might implement a sort of fake capture session using the camera, and the camera will not be available to other applications.

Either way, student user account should be restricted so that use could not stop your video application, could not re-enable the device interactively.