# C# How to get capability HardwareDisabled property for hardware device

Tags: c#, device-driver, human-interface

I am trying to tell if a hardware device (specifically multitouch digitizer) is **disabled**.

I can successfully enable/disable the device using the **DisableHardware** class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6877468/1868148).

I have found the **[DEVICE_CAPABILITIES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** struct with property **HardwareDisabled**. But if I call **SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW**, to return SPDRP_CAPABILITIES, I am unable to convert the returned value (DWORD) to useful uint.

I believe my conversion is wrong from byte[] => uint, I always get 128.

```
private static bool IsDeviceHardwareDisabeld(IntPtr info, SP_DEVINFO_DATA devdata)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("IsDeviceHardwareDisabeld");
    uint SPDRP_CAPABILITIES = 0x0000000F;
    uint CM_DEVCAP_HARDWAREDISABLED = 16384u;

    uint propId = SPDRP_CAPABILITIES;

    uint proptype, outsize;
    IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        uint buflen = 512;
        buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)buflen);
        outsize = 0;
        SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW(
            info,
            ref devdata,
            propId,
            out proptype,
            buffer,
            buflen,
            ref outsize);
        Trace.WriteLine("OUTSIZE: " + outsize.ToString()); // 4
        byte[] lbuffer = new byte[outsize];
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, lbuffer, 0, (int)outsize);
        int errcode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (errcode == ERROR_INVALID_DATA) throw new Exception("ERROR_INVALID_DATA");
        CheckError("SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW", errcode);

        uint capabilities = BitConverter.ToUInt32(lbuffer, 0); // always 128
        uint bitwise = capabilities & CM_DEVCAP_HARDWAREDISABLED; // always 0
        bool isHardwareDisabled = bitwise > 0;
        Trace.WriteLine("HARDWAREDISABLED: " + isHardwareDisabled.ToString());
        return isHardwareDisabled;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    }
}
```

My conversion always returns **128** for value of DEVICE_CAPABILITIES.