# C# Devcon functionality without Devcon?

Tags: c#, device-management

I have an app which is using DEVCON to do the following;

- Get device status
- Enable
- Disable
- All of the above based on compatible id's.

How can I do the same without using DEVCON at all? I still need the same functionality listed above.

I have looked into [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097000/how-do-i-disable-a-system-device-programatically/6877468#6877468) but I need to tailor it more towards the criteria above. It also needs to work on x86, x64 and XP+.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: DevCon as in the Microsoft Device Console?

Comment: yup, [Microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)

Answer (score 1):

To do it from C#, you'd have to pinvoke Windows [Setup APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550897(v=vs.85).aspx)

This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259695) has an example in C of how the Setup APIs can be used to enumerate devices.

And interestingly enough, there is a Powershell module available on TechNet for [Device Management](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Device-Management-7fad2388).

If the license allows it, you could take a peek at the implementation, which is in .Net.

Comment: I will look into pinvoke. the PS module fails on windows 8.1 and no source available...