# Disable/Enable PS/2 device programatically

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, wmi, device-driver

I have an HP Envy and for all it's good qualities it's got a horrible, dumb, always-in-the-way clickpad.

I've taken to disabling the device via Mouse Properties and then re-enabling it when I want to do mouse-based clicking.

[image: Disable device via Mouse Properties]

I'd like to hook up the toggling of this driver to a shortcut. I know how to do the shortcut key part using AutoHotKey, but don't know how to use the command line to disable a device. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe not strictly from the commandline but I'm sure you can create something from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097000/how-do-i-disable-a-system-device-programatically)

Comment: As a side note does it not have a setting where it is disabled if a mouse is attached?

Comment: I think the original software did, but I reinstalled the OS to get rid of junk (and use my own ssd) and the driver download for HP doesn't seem to include that functionality. Also, I want it even when no mouse is attached.

Answer (score 2):

1) Get [DevCon](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q311272) from Microsoft

2) Use (x64 version) with `devcon disable [DEVICENAME]`

3) Enjoy!

Comment: I get a *Disable Failed* message. Any ideas? `.\devcon.exe disable 'ACPI\SYN1ECA*'
ACPI\SYN1ECA\4&22077A96&0                                   : Disable failed`

Comment: One forum suggests that this is because I'm running the 386 version on 64bit windows, but the only 64 bit one available is for itanium architecture..

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. [I've spun this issue off into a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737232/devcon-disable-cannot-disable-device-not-found)