# Android Emulator connect external storage Device while running

Tags: kotlin, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-storage, qemu-device

I have an App that needs to detect, if a USB Storage device is getting mounted. Can i simulate the mounting of an USB Storage Device while the Emulator is already running? This way i can debug the behavior of my app.

As i know, for registering the mounting and unmounting of the USB Storage Device i can use the `StorageVolumeCallback()`. What do i have to do to write a simple .txt File to that attached USB Storage Device?

Im having trubble to create a StorageManager inside my ViewModel because i do not have access to the `Context`.

Im thankful for any Tipp related to USB Storage Management at all.

Info:
API Version: 31
IDE: Android Studio
Language: Kotlin

Edit:
So i do not necessarily need to have a external usb drive mounted at startup. If its possible with adb it would be great if i could just forward a usb Pendrive to the running emulator when i need it. Something like `adb connectUsbDevice -deviceid=****,vendorid=***`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a .NET library I'm aware of which can do this. However, please refer to this post where the brilliant answer shows how to do this interfacing with the Win 32 API.

[How do I disable a system device programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097000/how-do-i-disable-a-system-device-programmatically)

You'll need a combination of this, and a WMI query to find an attached PnP device of type storage.  As a clue:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_USBHub"))
        {
            collection = searcher.Get();
        }
```

Change Win32_USBHub to the correct class if this isn't giving you what you're looking for.

EDIT: Be warned. If you're disabling storage devices, make sure they're not in use. That's what the "Safely remove USB" option is for in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you don't need to emulate this in code, use a real USB storage device inserted in the system and use PowerShell to get, disable, and enable the device.

The Cmdlets you'll need are:

Get-PnpDevice
Disable-PnpDevice
Enable-PnpDevice

Comment: Im using Kubuntu. 

Yes, i want to test it with a real USB Stick plugged into my Laptop. 
The testcase is following:

1. I start the Emulator and install the App
2. The App runs in the Emulator
3. I plug in a real USB Storage Stick in my real Laptop
4. The App need to get the "new" USB external Storage Device
5. Writes Data to the external USB Storage

Comment: OK. That was unclear and I assumed you were using Windows. Please edit your question and include OS and programming language. Also see https://snapcraft.io/install/powershell/kubuntu. You can install Linux PowerShell.