Broadcasting WM_SETTINGCHANGE doesn't update setting in Settings app
I'm trying to write some code to programmatically disable and reenable the touchpad. I've written code to update the registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\Status\Enabled, which works fine. I then need to broadcast WM_SETTINGCHANGE, which I've attempted with the following code:
    private const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF;
    private const uint WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1A;
    private const int MSG_TIMEOUT = 15000;

    // Enum for SendMessageTimeout flags
    [Flags]
    private enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
    {
        SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0000,
        SMTO_BLOCK = 0x0001,
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002,
        SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x0008,
        SMTO_ERRORONEXIT = 0x0020
    }

    // PInvoke declaration
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        uint Msg,
        UIntPtr wParam,
        IntPtr lParam,
        SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags,
        uint uTimeout,
        out UIntPtr lpdwResult);

    private static void BroadcastChange()
    {
        IntPtr hwndBroadcast = new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST);
        string environment = "Environment";

        // Allocate memory for the string parameter
        IntPtr lParam = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(environment);

        try
        {
            UIntPtr result;
            SendMessageTimeout(
                hwndBroadcast,
                WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
                UIntPtr.Zero,
                lParam,
                SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
                MSG_TIMEOUT,
                out result);

            Console.WriteLine("Broadcast message sent successfully.");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Free the allocated memory
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lParam);
        }
    }

When this code is executed (after changing the key value) I expect the touchpad to stop working but it continues to work. In addition, I expect the following Settings app toggle to change, but it does not:

What am I doing wrong?
This is a .net 8 console app.
Edit:
Link to repo with complete copy of code:
https://github.com/IanPNewson/AutoDisableTouchpad

Looks like you should instead use the Devices WINAPI functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097000/how-do-i-disable-a-system-device-programmatically or use Powershell.Create and call Disable-PnpDevice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/disable-pnpdevice?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Applications might react to WM_SETTINGCHANGE but don't have to. And "Environment" should be about env variables. I assume Registry keys don't count as Environment. From the documentation of that Windows Message about lParam This string can be the name of a registry key or the name of a section in the Win.ini file

@Charlieface I only need to target Windows 11, so I don't think the approach in that question is necessary

I think the WM_SETTINGCHANGE is sent after something changed. Your problem is that the registry key will not disable the touchpad but someone needs to reread the touchpad settings again and respond to it. That is not necessarily a listener of the WM_SETTINGCHANGE event.

Please install the "InputSimulatorEx" nugget package in the project or any tool that allows simulating the sending of the "Windows" button combination.
The following code enables or disables the touchpad without the need to restart:
public static void ToggleEnableDisableTouchpad()
{
    var KeystrokeSimulator = new InputSimulator();
    KeystrokeSimulator.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(new List<VirtualKeyCode>() { VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL }, VirtualKeyCode.F24);
}


More details:
Microsoft explains in the following link that:
"The state of the touchpad will be toggled when the CTRL + WIN + F24 keyboard combination is reported to the host."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-enable-or-disable-toggle-button
It should be noted that following registry changes are applied after restarting the laptop:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\Status\Enabled
In some laptops, there is a key combination to enable or disable the touchpad without the need to restart (for example, in Asus Q530, first the Fn+ESE button and then the F6 button changes the touchpad status), but usually that laptop manufacturer, does not use the Microsoft touchpad driver and they design their own driver and probably do this through the SDK of that driver.
In Windows SDK (10.0.26100) for Windows 11, there is a solution for changing the touchpad parameters that can be used from Windows 11, version 24H2 onwards, and that is the use of "SPI_SETTOUCHPADPARAMETERS" in the "SystemParametersInfo" function.
But in the documentation for the input data ("TOUCHPAD_PARAMETERS"), it is mentioned that the "touchpadEnabled" field is ignored in "SPI_SETTOUCHPADPARAMETERS".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-touchpad_parameters
Maybe if enabling and disabling the touchpad could be done without restarting the computer for any laptop easily, they would apply it in that function.
Perhaps checking the functions that are called when pressing the Win+Ctrl+F24 buttons and the messages that are sent in Windows can lead us to the direct way of enabling and disabling the touchpad.

Probably, the "WM_SETTINGCHANGE" message is not the right way to change the status of the touchpad without restarting, because it is written in "WinUser.h":
#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)
#define WM_SETTINGCHANGE                WM_WININICHANGE
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */

That is, in software development with C++ for Windows 11 using Visual Studio, the message WM_SETTINGCHANGE is equal to WM_WININICHANGE.
According to the link below, the WM_WININICHANGE message applies to things that are either in Win.ini or in the equivalent path in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-wininichange
I think there is currently no setting to enable and disable the touchpad in that registry path.
