# Is there a way to disable/enable touchscreen programmatically without rebooting or signing out in Windows 10?

Tags: .net, winapi, touchscreen

I have perhaps a silly question, but I am curious to find out if, you can code a program, for instance in c++, which would disable or enable touch screen without rebooting or signing out, in addition I just want to disable touchscreen and be still able to use pen on tablet. (**on windows 10**).

I know you can enable or disable touch screen by Device manager, but that is not what I am looking for. Also I know that you can tweak registries to disable/enable the touchscreen, but it only takes effect if one reboots or signs out.

I would just want to know if there is a way to do this. Is there any function for this in .net framework or win32? 
Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Perhaps this will help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252185/how-do-i-disable-a-system-device)

Comment: I saw this post, but I am not sure if disabling a device won`t disable tablet pen as well.

Comment: Is the tablet pen it's own device? I would think, yes. Give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to quickly enable and disable the touch screen, [DevCon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-general-commands) is a good option.

> DevCon (DevCon.exe) is a command line tool that can display detailed
>   information about devices on computers running Windows. You can also
>   use DevCon to enable, disable, install, configure, and remove devices.

You can use `DevCon` to create shortcut that can be quickly enabled and disabled.

**DevCon Enable:**

```
devcon [/r] enable {* | ID [ID ...] | =class [ID [ID ...]]}
```

**DevCon Disable:**

```
devcon [/r] disable {* | ID [ID ...] | =class [ID [ID ...]]}
```

Get the hardware ID, for example,  HID\VID_####&PID_####&COL##

Then create a Batch File

```
set "touchscreenid=ID_HERE"
devcon status "%touchscreenid%" | findstr "running"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    devcon disable "%touchscreenid%"
) else (
    devcon enable "%touchscreenid%"
)
```

Finally, change the properties of the file to make it a shortcut.

For details, you can refer [warrenj203's answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-disable-touchscreen/88afec2d-fef7-4f0e-8d91-da8b7c23f57a).

Hope to help you.